# Adding Bootstrap 3 Custom Components to Yeoman Angular project

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, yeoman

So I've been messing around with yeoman and angular a lot this past week and I've been able to incorporate bootstrap and ui-bootstrap into my yeoman angular project. However when I want to add a custom bootstrap component like a cover page (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/) that requires a different css file called cover.css.

I've tried linking it in my main.html, index.html and even @import it to my main.css file but whenever I "grunt serve" it comes out squashed and narrowed. Is this because the main.css file is overwriting the cover.css? Or maybe a better question is how to add a css file to a yeoman project?

This may be a stupid question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://bower.io/ it is used for dependency management no yeoman

Answer (score 0):

Yeoman doesn't directly handle CSS files from what I understand you have to do the part of linking the CSS files it will bring down for you manually.

Regarding overwriting in CSS the higher specificity wins assuming the same importance and the last in ordinarily wins if two classes have the same level of specificity.  In my project I'm just including the bootstrap.css and believe it contains everything else needed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
```

Perhaps you need to include the angularui project that has the templates (note the tpls in the name of the js file)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```